# How can i create a webservice the shortest route between two POIs?

Tags: web-service, route

I would like to create a prototype of a webservice that can calculate the shortest route between two POIs. How can I do that ?

(I don't have any knowledge about the back-end of GIS and webmapping. So if you know any gis server or tool that can simplify this task it will be very helpful. 
I prefer opensource free tools. However, A very good tool or server that worth the price will be helpful for me )

Comment: Can you please improve your question. What servers, GIS Sofware, Budget, if you ask a poor question expect no answers. Ask a good question you will get better answers. Please See http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this problem and many software programs that try to do it as well especially of note is Google Maps.  However, if you want to make your own, perhaps a good starting point would be using a very simple php snippet of Djikstra's algorithm such as [this one](http://www.algolist.com/code/php/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) where you would build your own graph on the fly.  This is probably not suitable for large-scale networks, but if your network is small enough it may work.